# Differential Equation: $\text dy/\text dx = x/y$

Tags: calculus

Consider the differential equation $\text dy/\text dx = x/y$

> a) Write an equation for the line tangent to the solution curve that passes through the point $(1,2)$

Would it be correct to just use the point slope form and just do $y-2 = m(x-1)$ where $m$ would be $1/2$?

> b) Find the particular solution $y=f(x)$ to the differential equation with the initial condition $f(3) = -1$

After separation and integration I get $y^2/2 = x^2/2 +C$, would I just plug the initial condition in and solve for $c$?

Also could someone explain how to sketch the solution curve on a slope field of $\text dy/\text dx$?

Comment: it would help if you can say what you have done and where you are having trouble.

Comment: @abel: "After separation and integration I get..." it seems like some of that has been demonstrated already.

Comment: Where are you stuck?, we can help you if you tell us what have you tried.

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLpez, I do not know if I'm doing it right

Comment: I think the general answer here is "yes, this is all as obvious as it sounds."  The slope field is just an extension of part (A), where you are picking every lattice point $(x,y)\in\Bbb Z^2$, perhaps within the bounds $x,y\in[-10,10]$ and sketching the slope at that point.

Comment: @abiessu, thanks for reminding me. the ops explanation and the question text were too close and i did not read it carefully. i see that op made good faith effort to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have done to answer part (a) is correct.  that is the the tangent to the integral curve at $x = 1, y = 2$ is $y-2 = \frac12 (x-1).$

for part (b), you can separate the variables and integrate(using the fundamental theorem of calculus) $$y \, dy = x\, dx \to \int_{-1}^yy\, dy = \int_3^xx \, dx $$  which gives you the particular solution $$y^2 - 1=x^2 - 9 \to f(x) = - \sqrt{x^2 - 8}$$

the solution curves are rectangular hyperbolas with asymptotes $y = \pm x.$

Comment: Why would f(x) not be positive?

Comment: @ILikeMath,  don't you need $f(3) = -1?$

Comment: well if it is negative that would just be the bottom portion of the hyperbola

Comment: @ILikeMath, that is why we picked the negative square root.

Comment: so for the graphing part of it, would I just sketch the curve over the dy/dx graph, cuz that is what I have - the dy/dx graph

Comment: the trajectories will follow the slope field; slope field is like the wind and the trajectory is like the path of a baloon.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that $dy/dx = 0$ when $x = 0$ (but $y ≠ 0$) and $dy/dx$ diverges as $y$ goes to $0$. Besides that, you basically just plug in random (nonzero) values for $x$ and $y$ and draw that slope on the $xy$-plane and see what it looks like.

Comment: So this is a little bit of the "how to sketch the solution curve on a slope field".  Do you have answers for the other questions listed?

Comment: For a), "Yes, that's right." For b) first question, "Yes, that's right."